# Trouble installing a Linux VM on XenServer 7

Tags: xen, citrix

I've been struggling to get a Linux guest running on XenServer 7.5.

Here is a sequence of commands that I've been running -- don't get any errors -- except when I run the VM, it does not seem to be able to boot the image.

```
xe vm-install template="CentOS 7" new-name-label=centos-7-11

xe vm-param-set uuid=ebf31974-e3d8-46f6-d895-b3104634d25d \
  other-config:install-repository=http://repos-tx.psychz.net/centos/7/os/x86_64/

xe network-list bridge=e9b7b721-68c6-57f1-2c42-04fc672e1a3e --minimal

xe vif-create vm-uuid=ebf31974-e3d8-46f6-d895-b3104634d25d \
  network-uuid=e9b7b721-68c6-57f1-2c42-04fc672e1a3e mac=random device=0

xe vm-start uuid=ebf31974-e3d8-46f6-d895-b3104634d25d
```

The Guest complains that it does not find a bootable device.